simple calculator program exiting unexpectedly after input (C, MinGW)
'm trying to write a basic calculator program in C using MinGW. However, the program exits unexpectedly after I enter the operator (+, -, *, or /). I've checked for common errors like missing return 0; and division by zero, but I can't seem to find the culprit. idk if something is wrong with the compiler
Here's my code
#include <stdio.h>



int main() {
  int number1, number2;
  double result;
  char op;

    printf("Enter the 1st number: v2 ");
    scanf("%d", &number1);
    getchar(); // Consume the newline

    printf("Enter the 2nd number: ");
    scanf("%d", &number2);
    getchar(); // Consume the newline
    printf("Enter an operator (+, -, *, or /) ");
    scanf(" %c", &op);
  

  switch (op) {
    case '+':
      result = number1 + number2;
      printf("%.2lf + %.2lf = %.2lf\n", number1, number2, result);
      break;

    case '-':
      result = number1 - number2;
      printf("%.2lf - %.2lf = %.2lf\n", number1, number2, result);
      break;

    case '/':
      result = (double)number1 / number2; // Handle division by zero
      printf("%.2lf / %.2lf = %.2lf\n", number1, number2, result);
      break;

    case '*':
      result = number1 * number2;
      printf("%.2lf * %.2lf = %.2lf\n", number1, number2, result);
      break;

    default:
      printf("Invalid operator\n");
      break;
  }

  return 0; 
} 

I ensured there was a return 0; statement at the end of your main function to indicate successful program termination
I reviewed how you were using scanf to read numeric input and the operator. I focused on potential issues with leftover newline characters (\n) from the numeric input affecting the scanf for the operator.

"the program exits unexpectedly": what does this mean?  And why are you formatting integers as doubles?

Those lf masks in printf are not compatible with int variables. Do enable all compiler warnings.

Aside: get rid of those getchar(); // Consume the newline kludges. They aren't even necessary here. What is important is to check that scanf did scan the required input type. And something is wrong with the compiler – there isn't. It's a failure to read man pages and compiler warnings, although scanf is tricky.

Pleas edit to show an example of running the program with input and output.

Some reading pursuant to @WeatherVane's comment on it not being the compielr's fault: It's always your fault

printf("Enter the 1st number: v2 ");  What does v2 mean?

@WeatherVane he can't just delete the getchar() calls. Try it out if you don't agree. With the scanf calls as written, the newlines are, in fact, not consumed by the scanf, leading to bad behavior in subsequent scanfs. You can get rid of the getchars if you change the scanfs, but just telling him to delete them is wrong.

@StreveFord excuse me but all leading whitespace is consumed by the scanf() calls as written. Format %d automatically filters leading whitespace. Format %c does not, except when written as " %c" with a leading space, which OP's code does. The only thing wrong with OP's use of scanf is not checking the function return value, which FYI is the number of items successfully scanned.

@WeatherVane I stand corrected. I've updated my answer. Thanks.

As the comments above already mentioned, don't use floating point conversions for integer arguments in your answer printf()s. It can get the stack messed up, which can produce unpredictable crashes. That was probably your main problem.
Different data types consume different amounts of memory. I don't have MinGW, so I can't experiment with doubles vs ints to get their exact sizes, but on any architecture you'll be likely to be using, a double is larger than an int. So your print call will push two ints and a double onto the stack and then call printf. Printf reads your format string and will attempt to consume three doubles off the stack, which will read past the values pushed. At a minimum, this will cause incorrect values to be printed, and can even cause hard crashes.
Although not the root of your problem, scanf()'s man page unhelpfully states:

It is very difficult to use these functions correctly, and it is preferable to read entire lines with fgets(3) or getline(3) and parse them later with sscanf(3) or more specialized functions such as strtol(3).

The scanf calls you have work properly, even without the getchar() calls. However, it is still generally recommended that you separate the input from the scanning. For one thing, if I run your program and for the first number I enter "1.1", it immediately responds with:
$ gcc x.c
$ ./a.out
Enter the 1st number: v2 1.1
Enter the 2nd number: Enter an operator (+, -, *, or /) Invalid operator

It is almost impossible to validate user input using scanf(). Reading the line with fgets() and then scanning with sscanf() gives you much more ability to validate input.

Perhaps an elaboration or link to further information on why providing mismatched data and formatting specifiers leads to stack issues: because printf doesn't know anything about the type of its arguments, and reads the memory as specified by the format specifiers.

The leading space before %d is entirely unnecessary, because the format automatically filters leading whitespace. You have overcomplicated what was already OK. The OP's fault was using %f to output int. I recommend you spend at least an hour exploring scanf and how it handles whitespace in the format string, and in the input strream. It's not the same for each format.

Not only that but the %*c may "steal" a required character from the input stream. Suppose the number is immediately followed by a letter which is required as part of the input. You have wrecked it. It's a mistake to presuppose what comes next in the input stream.

Huh. I could swear that I tested it just removing the getchars and it got out of sync with the newlines. But I tested again just now and it is as you say. I've updated my answer. Thanks for the correction.

You state that a double is definitely larger than an int. How comfortable are you that this additions is always true?

@Chris thanks for both of your guidances. I've softened my claim. But you're right - I'm sure there's some crazy architecture out there, or will be in the future, where an int and a double are the same size. Heck, I guess some future variant of X86 or ARM might do that, so all we can say with certainty is that we must never assume any particular size relationship. For the purposes of the OP's problem, I think my softened claim is ok.

get rid of the getchar() and replace the %.2lf with %d in the print statements for those int types.

Are you certain this is a solution to the problem rather than a comment?
